# SignalR In ASP.Net Core ~1.1

Tags: node.js, signalr, .net-core

I Want Create Real Time app In Asp.Net  Core 1.1 , But i no longer can use [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr) In My Application ,  help me to choose what frame work can be better for me ?  i must choose [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js)  or MicroSoft have  solution for us ? and i can use Alternative framework that be  similar to [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr)? !

> Microsoft.AspNetCore Version 1.1.1 
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc Version 1.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add https://dotnet.myget.org/f/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json to available package sources (Tools/Options/NuGet Package Manager/Package Sources)
2. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server package version 0.2.0-preview2-22683. You may need to adjust the "Package source" and check the "Include prerelease" checkbox in NuGet package manager to see the package in search results.
3. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets package (version 1.0.1).
4. Add services.AddSignalR(), app.UseWebSockets() and app.UseSignalR() calls to Startup.cs.

Works with Visual Studio 2017 and .NET Core 1.1.1.

Answer (score 2):

FYI the signalr packages in https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json (1.0.0*) target only the .NETStandard,Version=v2.0 platform now.

The older packages (0.2.0*) for ASP.NET Core 1.1 can be found in the repository
https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-dev/api/v3/index.json

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use SignalR 2 for now in ASP.NET Core 1.1 apps, as long as they target the full .NET framework instead of .NET core.

For that to work you need to create a Middleware-Wrapper for OWIN. [Yatajga](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/yatajga/) has [a nice sample over at MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-ASPNET-vNext-Real-Time-b1d27fe4).

Here's the interesting part (taken from said sample):

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Builder; 
using Owin; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder; 

namespace RealTimeDataEditor 
{
    using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>; 
 
    public static class BuilderExtensions 
    { 
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseAppBuilder( 
            this IApplicationBuilder app,  
            Action<IAppBuilder> configure) 
        { 
            app.UseOwin(addToPipeline => 
            { 
                addToPipeline(next => 
                { 
                    var appBuilder = new AppBuilder(); 
                    appBuilder.Properties["builder.DefaultApp"] = next; 

                    configure(appBuilder); 

                    return appBuilder.Build<AppFunc>(); 
                }); 
            }); 
            return app; 
        }
        public static void UseSignalR2(this IApplicationBuilder app) 
        {
            app.UseAppBuilder(appBuilder => appBuilder.MapSignalR()); 
        }
    }
}
```

and this way you can simply call `app.UseSignalR2();` inside the Configure() method in the Startup.cs file.

Disclaimer: SignalR 2 has not been developed for ASP.NET Core so there might be some issues when using it in production.

Comment: thx for ur answer but this solution just work for ASPNETCORE.NET462.
and doesnt work for ASPNETCORE.NETCORE:( 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wIsync6vTfQ

Comment: yes, that's what I was saying in the very first sentence ;-) But if you're planning on running on Windows hardware anyway, this might be the easiest solution.